# Using scala.sys.process with Future

Tags: scala, future

I am trying to execute something like this

```
scala> import scala.sys.process._
```

`scala> Process("cat temp.txt")!`

I will be doing this say in a Play Framework REST handler. I want this to return a future object so that I can map/flatMap on it and do further processing when the shell is done executing. How do I do that?

Comment: Have a look at the doc about `Future.apply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is this.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.sys.process._

val fs = Future("cat temp.txt".!!)  // Future[String] = Future(<not completed>)
```

The file contents becomes one long string but you can `split()` it in the `map()` operation.

Comment: with the default execution context, you should probably supports its mechanism for marking blocking threads, so `Future(blocking("cat temp.txt".!!))`